# Face tracking and detection

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am working in Unity3D and I want to make an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.msqrd.android&hl=ru) one. To do that, I need a nice and smooth sdk/library/whatever, that enables me to track face position with all the face landmarks(eyes, nose, mouth) and detect landmark position changes.

So far I've tried [OpenCV](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088) plugin, but it seems to work not too precisely. For example. when I run the demo scene, it tracks the face, but the face oval size gets distorted very easily and quickly, as well as landmark positions, which are distorted even from the very start.

I've also tried [XZIMG](http://www.xzimg.com/) plugin, but it does not track landmarks at all.
If I am doing something wrong, please correct me.

I am looking for an appropriate tool which can give me needed result on android and iOS devices. I've been looking into Google Mobile Vision, but so far I am not too sure that it can be easily integrated with Unity and used in iOS projects.

Comment: Your expectations for face recognition are unrealistic.

Comment: Possibly you are right, but I want to dig this topic up first.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm completely right, Sam  :)

Comment: But Joe, I do not need face recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image processing is an advanced topic. It's good to understand how the library you are using work before using it.

Speaking about tracking **being slow**, that's normal because it is CPU intensive and running it on mobile devices is another problem.

To **fix** slow problems,

**1**.You take an image, **send** it to a **server**(to Computer not mobile device). The server will do **all** the **processing** and **return** the result back to the **mobile** device.

**2**.Try [Vuforia](http://www.vuforia.com/). It is not free but it works with Unity.

**3**.Go **Native** and discard the use of Unity. You need more frames and using Unity will take away some frames. For Android, use **C++ NDK** and the **OpenCV C++**. For iOS use Objective-C and OpenCV. Image processing is one of the instances where using native code is recommended to get the **highest frame rate** as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've been using Vuforia to create AR application, but, as far as I know, this plugin does not give me any opportunity to track faces and face expressions. You are completely right about going native, but, unfortunately, in my case using Unity is critical because of cross-platform reasons. And when I was talking about OpenCV working wrong, I meant not slow, I ment wrong: it has distorted face positions, but you may be right about Unity making it work wrong.

Comment: If you meant working wrong, I suggest you first implement a FPS counter in your scene. If it is <10 then that's the problem. If you are sure that your FPS is good then what you need to do is learn image processing from scratch because your code is wrong somewhere. Even when you post your code here, it would be hard to get an answer for that topic.

Comment: Also, if what you are doing is taking a picture and applying effect (lion, cat, dog) after then Unity is fine. If you are doing live tracking and applying the effect live, then the native stuff I talked about is the way to go.

Comment: OpenCv face tracking samples: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html  http://synaptitude.me/blog/smooth-face-tracking-using-opencv/  You said you tried the one from the Asset store. If you bought it, you can ask your question there and they seller will likely help you pinpoint your problem. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/

Comment: The problem is that I am not even using any custom code yet. I am just running a demo scene, and though I have always 60 fps, it works awful. Thank you for your advise to contact the OpenCV developers, I will try to figure it out with them.

Comment: I was also thinking of finding some native tools for face tracking and integrating it as a plugin into my project by myself, but first of all I need to find such tools that work properly.

Comment: Yeah I think you should contact the developer in that forum. Just post your problem there and he/they will respond with a solution. Happy coding!